# Will Ubuntu installation type ERASE DISK AND INSTALL UBUNTU delete my internal SSD which has Windows and my files, etc.?

Tags: system-installation

I bought a 1 TB external SSD (SanDisk extreme) for school. I will primarily be using Linux OS and wanted to put it on an SSD and sort of make it a "portable PC" to keep everything school related together. However my Laptop has Windows 10 and an internal 500 gb SSD. When asked from Ubuntu what installation type to choose which should I choose? Would just saying erase disk and install Unbuntu delete nothing as there would be nothing on the external SSD? Or would this somehow also delete my internal SSD OS (Windows) and files as well somehow? I just want to make sure I don't mess this up. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can try disabling the internal SSD in the bios during your install, and then re-enable it after the installation is complete

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, if I were you, I would unplug the Windows SSD and put a new 1TB SSD to install an Ubuntu OS.

Comment: lIf you are always going to use external drive with one system, you can just let it install grub to internal drive. But better to have an ESP - efi system partition on external drive & either install grub to it (see bug report for way to do that) or copy files from /EFI/Boot & /EFI/ubuntu from internal drive's ESP to external drive's ESP. Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #23 & #26
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379

Comment: @Memnarchthemad : If you intend on using your Ubuntu SSD on different computers, some that boot BIOS and some that boot UEFI, it is possible to install Ubuntu so that it will handle both, (without overwriting your internal drives). See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-19-10-to-usb-device-step-by-step/1217839#1217839 This method will work with 18.04 as well as 19.10.

Comment: "Erase Disk" means exactly what it says.

Answer (score 1):

As you describe it, the ERASE DISK AND INSTALL UBUNTU, will most likely erase your Windows install on the internal 500GB drive.

You can use the "something else" option (at the bottom of the list) and then you should be able to differentiate between the 1TB external drive and the 500GB internal drive. Then you can install to the 1TB external without deleting the Windows installation.

There should be some decent YouTube videos out there for the details. This is often referred to as installing with "Manual Partitions".

Also keep in mind that running the Ubuntu OS from an external drive may make for a slow experience, but you won't know until you try it.